# Tax on income earned in the UK

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, non-resident, foreign-income

This is the first time I have paid taxes in the US. I am doing my best not to make a mistake. Here's the situation:

- Worked for three weeks in the UK in January 2015. I have paid UK taxes on this income.
- Moved to US and started working in late January under a J-1 visa.
- Transferred to H1b visa on October 1.

I am using the H&R Block online form. I am filing as a resident alien. AN advisor at H&R told me I qualify for "dual status" this year, and filing as a resident is probably simpler for me, and will make minimal difference financially. Were they correct in this advice?

My main question is how to declare the income I earned in the UK in the three weeks of January 2015? Do I have to pay taxes on it again? The H&R Block form has a section called "Foreign Wages or Pension Income". This seems appropriate. What exchange rate do I use to declare the income in USD?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the exchange rate portion: you use the IRS's annual [list of average exchange rates](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Yearly-Average-Currency-Exchange-Rates).

As for the tax, you need to tell the US government that you paid UK tax on those earnings. Unfortunately, I can't say how you do that using H&R Block. (Or even on normal IRS forms, TBH. I've never dealt with this situation before.)